# Conversion of a stacked bar chart to a 100% proportional stacked bar chart

Tags: charts, dashboard, qlikview

I am currently working on a dashboard to analyze the job market in Singapore. I made a stacked bar chart for job functions vs career level. My supervisor asked me to create a proportional stacked bar chart to see the clear difference in ratios of the career levels. 
The dimensions I used was Job Function (jobs of specific industry such as accounting, admin etc) and Career level (jobs of career level such as entry middle and senior) and 
The expressions I used was Count(Job Function). The issue is I can't make a proportional chart as the count of jobs varies for each career level for every job function.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a sample of the data and exactly how you are displaying it I cannot give you an example.

From what I understand you want the min and max values in the chart (on y axis) to not change based on your selections?

You would have to create a variable and get the max value for said chart, and use set analysis to ignore selections. You would then use this variable in your Properties->Axes->Scale on the object/chart.